# How to fetch json data using url and write it in file?

Tags: iphone, json, ios6, nsdocumentdirectory

[image]

As my above screen shot that  i have a json file (productDetail.json) in my app then i write file from json data like below code

```
else if([(MultipleURLConnection *)connection tag]==2)
    {
  if([fn writeToFile:responseData fileName:@"productDetail.json"])
       [self performSelector:@selector(loadingJSON) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
```

in above code responseData is NSMutableData and fn is function Class object name where i have below method

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSData *)data fileName:(NSString *)fileName 
 {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:myFile])  // if file doesn't exist, create it
    return ([fm createFileAtPath:myFile contents:data attributes:nil]);
else
    return ([data writeToFile:myFile atomically:YES]);  
 }
```

Now i decide to remove json file from app and to put it on server and then fetch it .so after putting json file on server i tried to fetch it like below coding

```
else if([(MultipleURLConnection *)connection tag]==2)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/Infomist/productDetail.json"];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if(jsonData != nil)
        {
            NSError *error = nil;

            id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if (error == nil)
              NSLog(@"show data %@",result);
       }
```

Now above method successfully fetching my data from server it show all my data in NSlog but problem for me is now how to modify this Method now

```
     if([fn writeToFile:responseData fileName:@"])
```

Beacuse after putting the json file on server i don't have any file to pass file name in above method to call the

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSData *)data fileName:(NSString *)fileName  .
```

I already have App flow  for local json file so i need only to write json data in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSData *)data fileName:(NSString *)fileName
```

the above requires `NSData` as a parameter

```
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

the above gives `id` as a return type object..you need to check which type of object it is using `isKindOfClass`

and then later convert it to data using **decoding/NSkeyedArchiver or other techniques**